# jquery validate SubmitHandler not firing after submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have developed a form that puts visible and required fields based on the answer of and ajax request. Initially the submitHandler was fired without problem, but after some edit to the code (just the js part) it seems that is not firing anymore and it is going directly to the submit event without allow me to add an hidden field to the request.

```
var API_ENDPOINT = "http://local.test/api";
var isMobile = window.innerWidth < 768;
var profileId = 2;
var childrenCookieSeparator = "|";

$(document).ready(function () {
    if (!isMobile) {
        $("#request-container").addClass('mobile');

}

// Init datepickers
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional["it"]);
$('.datepickercheckout').datepicker({
    minDate: 1,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    beforeShowDay:function(date){
        if(date.toString().indexOf('Sun ')!=-1) {
            return [1, 'weekend'];
        } else {
            if(date.toString().indexOf('Sat ')!=-1) {
                return [1, 'weekend'];
            } else {
                return [1];
            }
        }
    }
});

$('.datepickercheckin').datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    onClose: function(dateText,datePickerInstance) {
        var oldValue = $(this).data('oldValue') || "";
        if (dateText !== oldValue) {
            $(this).data('oldValue',dateText);
            var from = dateText.split("/")
            var dat = new Date(from[2], from[1] - 1, from[0])
            dat.setDate(dat.getDate() + 1)
            $('.datepickercheckout').datepicker("setDate", dat );
            $('.datepickercheckout').datepicker('option', 'minDate', dat);
        }
    },
    beforeShowDay:function(date){
        if(date.toString().indexOf('Sun ')!=-1) {
            return [1, 'weekend'];
        } else {
            if(date.toString().indexOf('Sat ')!=-1) {
                return [1, 'weekend'];
            } else {
                return [1];
            }
        }
    }
});


// Init timepickers
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
    interval: 30,
    dynamic: false,
    dropdown: true,
    scrollbar: true
});

var firstChild = $('[name="children[]"]');
var removeFirstChild = $('.remove-child');
removeFirstChild.on('click', function (e) {
    firstChild.remove();
    $(e.target).remove();
});

var form = $("#request-form");

var inputFields = {
    'checkin_date': form.find("[name='checkin_date']"),
    'checkout_date': form.find("[name='checkout_date']"),
    'checkin_time': form.find("[name='checkin_time']"),
    'checkout_time': form.find("[name='checkout_time']"),
    'name': form.find("[name='name']"),
    'email': form.find("[name='email']"),
    'phone': form.find("[name='phone']"),
    'adults': form.find("[name='adults']"),
    'children': form.find("[name='children[]']"),
    'additional_requests': form.find("[name='additional_requests']"),
    'address': form.find("[name='address']"),
    'city': form.find("[name='city']"),
    'zip_code': form.find("[name='zip_code']"),
    'phone_2': form.find("[name='phone_2']"),
    'phone_3': form.find("[name='phone_3']"),
    'treatment_id': form.find("[name='treatment_id']")
};

var validation = {
    'name': {maxlength: 16},
    'email': {maxlength: 255},
    'phone': {maxlength: 45},
    'adults': {min: 0},
    'children[]': {min: 0},
    'additional_requests': {maxlength: 255},
    'address': {maxlength: 255},
    'city': {maxlength: 150},
    'zip_code': {maxlength: 16},
    'phone_2': {maxlength: 45},
    'phone_3': {maxlength: 45}
};

isMobile = isMobile ? 1 : 0;
$.ajax({
    url: API_ENDPOINT + "/profiles/" + profileId + "/fields?is_mobile=" + isMobile
})
    .done(function (data) {
        var fields = data.fields;
        fields.push('name', 'email');
        var requiredFields = data.required_fields;
        requiredFields.push('name', 'email');

        var treatments = data.treatments;
        var treatmentsSelect = $("#treatment_id");

        // Add treatments
        for (var id in treatments) {
            if (treatments.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
                treatmentsSelect.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + treatments[id] + '</option>');
            }
        }

        // Set visible fields
        fields.forEach(function (value, index) {
            $("#" + value + "_input").show();

            if (value === 'children') {
                var cookie = Cookies.get('form_children');
                if (cookie && cookie !== "") {
                    // Remove first child
                    removeFirstChild.click();

                    // Add other children
                    var children = cookie.split(childrenCookieSeparator);

                    children.forEach(function (age) {
                        addChild(age);
                    })
                }
            } else {
                inputFields[value].val(Cookies.get("form_" + value));
            }
        });

        // Set required fields
        requiredFields.forEach(function (value, index) {
            inputFields[value].attr('required', true);
        });

        // Add other rules to fields
        for (var field in validation) {
            var input = $('[name="' + field + '"]');

            input.prop(validation[field]);
        }

        if (inputFields.children.prop('required')) {
            removeFirstChild.remove();
        }

        function addChild(age) {
            var newChildContainer = $('<div class="children-div"></div>');
            var newChildString = '<select id="children_' + i + '" class="input input-children" name="children[]"> ' +
                '<option value="0" ' + ((age === "0") ? "selected" : "") + '>0</option> ' +
                '<option value="1" ' + ((age === "1") ? "selected" : "") + '>1</option> ' +
                '<option value="2" ' + ((age === "2") ? "selected" : "") + '>2</option> ' +
                '<option value="3" ' + ((age === "3") ? "selected" : "") + '>3</option> ' +
                '<option value="4" ' + ((age === "4") ? "selected" : "") + '>4</option> ' +
                '<option value="5" ' + ((age === "5") ? "selected" : "") + '>5</option> ' +
                '<option value="6" ' + ((age === "6") ? "selected" : "") + '>6</option> ' +
                '<option value="7" ' + ((age === "7") ? "selected" : "") + '>7</option> ' +
                '<option value="8" ' + ((age === "8") ? "selected" : "") + '>8</option> ' +
                '<option value="9" ' + ((age === "9") ? "selected" : "") + '>9</option> ' +
                '<option value="10" ' + ((age === "10") ? "selected" : "") + '>10</option> ' +
                '<option value="11" ' + ((age === "11") ? "selected" : "") + '>11</option> ' +
                '<option value="12" ' + ((age === "12") ? "selected" : "") + '>12</option> ' +
                '<option value="13" ' + ((age === "13") ? "selected" : "") + '>13</option> ' +
                '<option value="14" ' + ((age === "14") ? "selected" : "") + '>14</option> ' +
                '<option value="15" ' + ((age === "15") ? "selected" : "") + '>15</option> ' +
                '<option value="16" ' + ((age === "16") ? "selected" : "") + '>16</option> ' +
                '<option value="17" ' + ((age === "17") ? "selected" : "") + '>17</option> ' +
                '</select>';
            var newChild = $(newChildString);

            newChildContainer.append(newChild);
            childrenDiv.append(newChildContainer);
        }

        $("#children_number").change(function() {
            var childrenDiv = $("#children");
            childrenDiv.empty();

            var val =  $( this ) . val()
            if ( val >= 1) {
                var newLabelContainer = $('<div></div>');
                var newLabelString = '<label>Quanti anni hanno i bambini con cui viaggi?</label>'
                var newLable = $(newLabelString);
                newLabelContainer.append(newLable);
                childrenDiv.append(newLabelContainer);
            }

            for(i = 0; i < val; i++) {
                var newChildContainer = $('<div class="children-div"></div>');
                var newChildString = '<select id="children_' + i + '" class="input input-children" name="children[]"> ' +
                    '<option value="0" selected>0</option> ' +
                    '<option value="1">1</option> ' +
                    '<option value="2">2</option> ' +
                    '<option value="3">3</option> ' +
                    '<option value="4">4</option> ' +
                    '<option value="5">5</option> ' +
                    '<option value="6">6</option> ' +
                    '<option value="7">7</option> ' +
                    '<option value="8">8</option> ' +
                    '<option value="9">9</option> ' +
                    '<option value="10">10</option> ' +
                    '<option value="11">11</option> ' +
                    '<option value="12">12</option> ' +
                    '<option value="13">13</option> ' +
                    '<option value="14">14</option> ' +
                    '<option value="15">15</option> ' +
                    '<option value="16">16</option> ' +
                    '<option value="17">17</option> ' +
                    '</select>';
                var newChild = $(newChildString);

                newChildContainer.append(newChild);
                childrenDiv.append(newChildContainer);
            }
        });

        // Show form
        form.show();

        // Validate form on send
        form.validate({
            submitHandler: function (nativeForm) {
                nativeForm.append('<input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="' + profileId + '"/>');

                // Save cookies
                fields.forEach(function (value, index) {
                    var val = inputFields[value].val();

                    // Save every child
                    if (value === 'children') {
                        val = [];
                        form.find("[name='children[]']").each(function (i, c) {
                            val.push($(c).val());
                        });
                        val = val.join(childrenCookieSeparator);
                    }

                    Cookies.set("form_" + value, val);
                });

                nativeForm.submit();
            }
        });

    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

The form is the following:

```
<div id="request-container">
    <form style="display: none" id="request-form" action="http://local.test/api/requests" method="POST">
        <div style="display: none" id="checkin_date_input">
            <input id="checkin_date" class="input datepickercheckin" name="checkin_date" placeholder="Check-in" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="checkin_time_input">
            <input id="checkin_time" class="input timepicker" name="checkin_time" placeholder="Orario di check-in" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="checkout_date_input">
            <input id="checkout_date" class="input datepickercheckout" name="checkout_date" placeholder="Check-out" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="checkout_time_input">
            <input id="checkout_time" class="input timepicker" name="checkout_time" placeholder="Orario di check-out" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="name_input">
            <input class="input" id="name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="email_input">
            <input class="input" id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="phone_input">
            <input class="input" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Telefono" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="adults_input">
            <select id="adults" class="input" name="adults">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Adulti</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
              <option value="11">11</option>
              <option value="12">12</option>
              <option value="13">13</option>
              <option value="14">14</option>
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
              <option value="17">17</option>
              <option value="18">18</option>
              <option value="19">19</option>
              <option value="20">20</option>
              <option value="21">21</option>
              <option value="22">22</option>
              <option value="23">23</option>
              <option value="24">24</option>
              <option value="25">25</option>
              <option value="26">26</option>
              <option value="27">27</option>
              <option value="28">28</option>
              <option value="29">29</option>
              <option value="30">30</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="children_input">
            <select id="children_number" class="input" name="children_number">
              <option value="" disabled selected>Bambini</option>
              <option value="0">0</option>
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="2">2</option>
              <option value="3">3</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="6">6</option>
              <option value="7">7</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="9">9</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <div id="children">

             </div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="address_input">
            <input class="input" id="address" name="address" placeholder="Indirizzo" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="city_input">
            <input class="input" id="city" name="city" placeholder="Città" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="zip_code_input">
            <input class="input" id="zip_code" name="zip_code" placeholder="CAP" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="phone_2_input">
            <input class="input" id="phone_2" name="phone_2" placeholder="Telefono (2)" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="phone_3_input">
            <input class="input" id="phone_3" name="phone_3" placeholder="Telefono (3)" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: none" id="treatment_id_input">
            <select class="input" id="treatment_id" name="treatment_id">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Trattamento</option>
            </select>
        </div>   
        <div style="display: none" id="additional_requests_input">
            <textarea id="additional_requests" name="additional_requests" class="input"
                        placeholder="Richieste aggiuntive"
            ></textarea>
        </div>         



        <input type="checkbox" id="privacy" checked required> Privacy policy

        <button id="request-form-send" type="submit">Invia richiesta</button>
    </form>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="request.css">
<script src="request.js"></script>
```

I've already tried to put breakpoint and console log inside the submit handler and it does not work. I've also tried to change the submit button in input element with "submit" value but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Way too much code.  Please strip it down to just enough that still reproduces the issue.  When the validation is bypassed, it usually means the JavaScript is totally broken... are you sure you're not seeing any console errors.  Put `debug: true` option within `.validate()` method and check console again.

Comment: Quote:  *"but after some edit to the code... that is not firing anymore"* ~ it might be helpful to share what edits you made.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the field `<input type="checkbox" id="privacy" checked required>` that was without a "name" attribute. This caused an exception that, without "debug: true" option on validate function, wasn't shown.

Comment: That's the whole point of the `debug` option.   Otherwise, leaving off the `name` attribute is not a JavaScript error nor compliance issue.

Comment: Simply omitting the `name` attribute of one input would not stop the remaining validation unless that was the only `input` being validated.